# Syntax error for INDEX formula using Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm getting a syntax error when I try to insert a formula in a cell using Macro. I can't seem to figure out what am I doing wrong? The formula works fine when I manually enter it. Here's my code:

```
ws3.Range("F2:F" & lastRow3).Formula = "=INDEX($L$1:INDEX(L:L,MATCH("ZZZ",D:D)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($K$1:INDEX(K:K,MATCH("ZZZ",D:D)))/($K$1:INDEX(K:K,MATCH("ZZZ",D:D))=D2),COUNTIF($D$1:$D2,D2)))"
```

ws3 is the worksheet, and lastRow3 is just to autofill the contents by comparing to a column to the left. Any ideas why this is giving an error?

FYI: This formula is finding values in one column from another column and giving the adjacent entries.

Comment: common mistake, replace "ZZZ" with ""ZZZ""

Comment: This works too, but I guess this makes excel unstable. It takes a long time to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filling a full range it is best to use R1C1 format.

Also with using vba to set the last row there is no reason for all the `INDEX(L:L,MATCH("ZZZ",D:D))` to find the last row, since the code itself can set it directly.

Use this:

```
ws3.Range("F2:F" & lastRow3).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX(R1C12:R" & lastrow & "C12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(R1C11:R" & lastrow & "C11)/(R1C11:R" & lastrow & "C11=RC[-2]),COUNTIF(R1C4:RC4,RC[-2])))"
```

Comment: @harry71152 okay, it is a result.  copy and paste what the formula is in F2, the one that the code put in there. Paste it in the comments here.

Comment: `INDEX($L$1:$L$55,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($K$1:$K$55)/($K$1:$K$55)=D2),COUNTIF($D$1:$D2,D2))`

Comment: @harry71152 i had a `)` in the wrong place.  See edit.